# My navbar drop-down links aren't working

Tags: css, laravel, navbar

So I'm experiencing a really weird problem where the links on my navbar work well but the ones which are drop-downs don't actually work ( click on them but they don't take me to any page), strangely they work if I double click and open in new tab.

What could be causing this?

```css
.nav_maincontainer{width:100%; height:50px; display:flex; align-items:center; padding:0px 100px; background-color:#004771; position:relative;}

.nav_link{font-size:17px; padding:0px 30px; color:white; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; height:100%; width:auto; }

.nav_dropdown{width:auto; height:100%; position:relative;}

.fa-caret-down{color:white; font-size:10px; margin-left:5px;}

.nav_dropdown_contents{display:none; min-width:300px; flex-direction:column; height:auto; position:absolute; top:100%; left:0px; z-index:9999999999999999;}

.nav_dropdown_link{padding:15px 10px; background-color:#383838; display:flex; align-items:center; font-size:15px; transition:all 600ms ease; color:white; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.0);}

.nav_dropdown_link:hover {background-color:#111111;}

.nav_menu_toggle{font-size:20px; color:white; display:none; width:50px; height:50px; }

.nav_dropdown:hover .nav_dropdown_contents{ display:flex;}

.nav_dropdown_contents:hover .nav_link{background-color:#072060;}

.nav_link:hover{background-color:#072060;}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_maincontainer" style="">
    <a class="nav_menu_toggle" href="" onclick="">
        <span class="nav_menu_text">Menu</span>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="nav_link {{ $pageInfo['menu_active']=='Inicio' ? 'active' : '' }}" href="/" title="Página de inicio" style="margin-righ:auto;">Inicio</a>
 <div class="nav_dropdown" style="margin-left:auto; ">
        <a class="nav_link {{ $pageInfo['menu_active']=='Clases' ? 'active' : '' }}" href="/clases" title="">Servicios 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" style=""></i>
        </a>
        <div class="nav_dropdown_contents" style="">
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Clases a domicilio' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/clases/domicilio">Clases a domicilio</a>
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Clases en grupo' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/clases/grupo">Clases en grupo</a>
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Clases a cachorros' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/clases/cachorros">Clases a cachorros</a>
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Clases de adiestramiento canino por sKype' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/clases/clases-adiestramiento-canino-por-skype">Clases por Skype<i class="fa fa-skype" style="color:white; font-size:25px; margin-left:auto; padding-left:10px;"></i></a>
   <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Obediencia' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/conductas/obediencia">Obediencia</a>
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Ansiedad' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/conductas/ansiedad">Ansiedad</a>
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Agresividad' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/conductas/agresividad">Agresividad</a>
   <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Miedo' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/conductas/miedo">Miedo</a>
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Hiperactividad' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/conductas/hiperactividad">Hiperactividad</a>
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Ladridos' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/conductas/ladridos">Ladridos</a>
  </div>
    </div>
    <a class="nav_link {{ $pageInfo['menu_active']=='Quienes somos' ? 'active' : '' }}" href="/quienes-somos">Quienes somos</a>
 <div class="nav_dropdown" style="">
        <a class="nav_link {{ $pageInfo['menu_active']=='Formate con nosotros' ? 'active' : '' }}" href="/formate-con-nosotros">Formate con nosotros 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" style=""></i>
        </a>
        <div class="nav_dropdown_contents" style="">
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Formación básica' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/formate-con-nosotros/formación-basica">Formació básica</a>
            <a class="nav_dropdown_link {{ $pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Formación avanzada' ? 'active_sub' : '' }}" href="/formate-con-nosotros/formacion-avanzada">Formación avanzada</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="nav_link {{ $pageInfo['menu_active']=='Contactar' ? 'active' : '' }}" href="/contactar" style="">Contactar</a>
    <a class="nav_link {{ $pageInfo['menu_active']=='Testimonios' ? 'active' : '' }}" href="/testimonios-de-nuestros-clientes" style="">Testimonios</a>
 <a class="nav_link {{ $pageInfo['menu_active']=='Preguntas' ? 'active' : '' }}" href="/preguntas-y-respuestas" style="">Preguntas</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: check if there is a click event written for those drop-downs

Comment: The code you provided works which most likely means there is either a JS conflict or there is a CSS conflict. I would test the click event like @MehravishTemkar is suggesting using a `console.log()` or something similar. Additionally, I would play with the `z-index` on the hovered elements to see iff that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which your your actual problem can you try this I think it work for you...

You can use on your link path like this.

> {{URL::to('your URL')}}